# paragraph indent and line spacing

Tags: paragraphs, parindent

In my text, I let make the paragraph indent automatically by LaTeX. That means everywhere I want to have a paragraph indentation in my text, I just press the enter key twice. However, when I look at the PDF version, I see that the line spacing above and below the paragraph input lines are different. Do you know how to fix this? I circled it red in the picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[table]{skip=4pt}
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[figure]{skip=3pt}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\onehalfspacing
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{10pt}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
```

......

```
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: TeX is not Word! Never use multiple Enter to get a vertical space! Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: I'm using article

Comment: Better post a MWE, i.e., a Minimal Working Example. Without it, answering your questions comes down to guessing.

Comment: use only _an empty line_ between paragraphs! Without the double backslashes for a new line!

Comment: hmm but I'm already using an empty line between...

Comment: please give a working sample!

Comment: The image does not reflect the text

Comment: and now.......?

Comment: Now it does, but I can’t see how that would happen. Is that happening at every paragraph?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I have the problem over the whole text.

Comment: please fix your example so that we can run it top debug the bad output.

Comment: Usually \parskip has some glue, which allows LaTeX to stretch or shrink the text in order to fit be bottom of the page.  Use \raggedbottom to bypass (overwhelm) this feature.

Answer (score 1):

In fact sometimes we should adjust the space between paragraphs. You can try the following codes before `\begin{document}`:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{x\baselineskip}%set space between paragraphs
```

where x can be any value as you wish. Also `x\baselineskip` can be changed for `x em` or `x pt`.

By setting `x\baselineskip` to be `0.2\baselineskip`, you can get a PDF as follows
[image]

Comment: I chose \onehalfspacing in the beginning and would like to keep it that way throughout the text. However, whenever there is a paragraph, just above as in the picture, the line spacing decreases.

Comment: My codes can give a global setting! It's better than your setting since  my codes only change parskip! You can have a try.

Comment: this does not answer the question at all which is about vaying line space, also the suggested code removes any stretch or shrink component from `\parskip` which may not be advisable, especially for classes using `\flushbottom`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please consider elucidating your comment as an answer. The other comments are probably unhelpful, and the OP might not grasp your own short comment. The reason I don't answer it myself, is because I use a very different layout structure, so what works for me might not work for others.

Comment: @RobtAll unless the OP edits the question I can't see how anyone can even attempt a guess at an answer.  There is currently no hint of the markup that produced the output shown.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code  not valid MWE. If you change the dots by six medium paragraphs (or easier: `\lipsum[1-6]` with  `\usepackage{lipsum}` in the preamble) you will not see that effect.

Adding a `\parskip` like `0pt minus 1 ex` before of the paragraphs (in the preamble or after that) allow ***sometimes*** a negative paragraph skip (note that with only four paragraphs, i.e. `\lipsum[1-4]`, that  does not change anything) that look like your problem ([see image bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVcum.png)).

In you real document you probably have something like `\setlength\parskip{0pt minus 1 ex}` or something else (some other package, for example) changing that glue.

You can test the real values of \parskip at any point (for instance, after
the word "Spain", including `\the\parskip`. If this renders some like "`0.0pt`**`minus`**`5.165pt`" you should expect sometimes some lost of space between paragraphs.

In case of default values (`0.0pt plus 1.0pt`) or any other positive paragraph skip glue, then the problem is hard to guess, except if you  provide a real MWE, reducing your real document as far as possible  *while still showing the problem* but *without* left any irrelevant code (as probably, many of the listed packages). Probably some as simple like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\parskip{0pt minus 1 ex}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
This document have a park skip of \the\parskip
\end{document}
```

> [image]